# Construct a query as a condition to insert set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I will try to explain but, if it is not clear, please let me know. English is not my first language.

I need some help with a query that would serve as condition to insert set of records or not.

First, I've got a db table EmployeeProviders.

In one of the stored procedures, I recalculate credits according to some condition. Records are set in quantities of in this case three but, could be more or less.

If after recalculation I get exactly the same numbers or credits with the same effective date as in EmployeeProviders I do not need to insert these values. EmployeeProviders may contain few sets of records for each employee separated by effective date.

The difficulty for me is to construct a query that will check records not one by one but in sets of three in this case. If one of the records does not match, I need to insert all three. If all of them the same, I do not insert any records.

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @employee_id int
select @StartDate = '2013-07-01', @employee_id = 3465
```

For example here is the db table populated with values

```
    DECLARE @EmployeeProviders TABLE (
    ident_id int IDENTITY,
                employee_id int,
    id int, 
    plan_id int, 
    credits decimal(18,5),
    effective_date datetime                     
)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
VALUES (18753, 23, 0.00000, '2013-06-01')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
VALUES (3465, 18753, 15, 0.00000, '2013-06-01')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
VALUES (3465, 18753, 16, 60.00, '2013-06-01')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
VALUES (3465, 18753, 23, 0.00000, '2013-07-01')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
VALUES (3465, 18753, 15, 0.00000, '2013-07-01')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
VALUES (3465, 18753, 16, 81.580, '2013-07-01')

SELECT * FROM @EmployeeProviders WHERE plan_id = 18753 and datediff(dd,effective_date,@StartDate) = 0
```

Here is the temp table in stored procedure. It gets updated during caclulation process

```
DECLARE @Providers TABLE (
    id int, 
    plan_id int, 
    credits decimal(18,5)                           
)

INSERT INTO @Providers (plan_id, id, credits)
VALUES (18753, 23, 0.00000)

INSERT INTO @Providers (plan_id, id, credits)
VALUES (18753, 15, 0.00000)

INSERT INTO @Providers (plan_id, id, credits)
VALUES (18753, 16, 81.580)

SELECT * FROM @Providers
```

After all updates amounts in this temp table are the same as in db table EmployeeProviders so, I do not need to insert new set of records
How can I do one query that can either be a condition like 
IF NOT EXISTS() 
or just do 
INSERT EmployeeProviders ()...
SELECT ... FROM @Providers ,,, -- query that would return me set of 3 records if values are not the same as in EmployeeProviders

Another scenario, @Providers.credits = 65 so, because the amount is changed compare to EmployeeProviders.credits for id = 16. I will add new set of 3 records to EmployeeProvider table

```
    DECLARE @Providers TABLE (
    id int, 
    plan_id int, 
    credits decimal(18,5)                           
)

INSERT INTO @Providers (plan_id, id, credits)
VALUES (18753, 23, 0.00000)

INSERT INTO @Providers (plan_id, id, credits)
VALUES (18753, 15, 0.00000)

INSERT INTO @Providers (plan_id, id, credits)
VALUES (18753, 16, 65.00)

SELECT * FROM @Providers
```

Thank you in advance,

Mak

Comment: your question is still unclear . can you please explain it more ?

Comment: If the result from both tables is the same, ids and amounts for them are the same I do not need to insert new records into EmployeeProviders. For example EmployeeProviders.id = Providers.id and EmployeeProviders.credits= Providers.credits for EmployeeProviders.effective_date = Jul 1, 2013. All three records must be the same. If Providers.credits after recalculation for one of the records will be 65 then, I will add new set of 3 records

Comment: The unique identifier for each row in 3 record - set is "id"

Comment: one more question you will compare credit one by one row for same employee or you will compare sum of credit for same employee ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a stab at it. Try this in the stored procedure:

```
if (EXISTS(select 3465,pr.plan_id,pr.id,epr.credits,effective_date from
   providers pr left join @EmployeeProviders epr on
   pr.id = epr.id and pr.plan_id = epr.plan_id and pr.credits = epr.credits and    effective_date = '2013-07-01'
   where epr.credits is NULL ))
 INSERT INTO @EmployeeProviders (employee_id, plan_id, id, credits, effective_date)
 select 3463,plan_id,id,credits,'2013-07-01' from @Providers
```

See it in [action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1b5f/15)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem can be solved by making your insert conditional on the outcome of an `Except`

```
if exists(
select ID, plan_id , credits from @Providers
except
SELECT id, plan_id, credits FROM @EmployeeProviders WHERE plan_id = 18753 and   datediff(dd,effective_date,@StartDate) = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like following query . i made it generalize for you . check it .

```
WITH TEMP 
AS
(
SELECT A.employee_id, A.plan_id, A.id, A.credits, A.effective_date,CASE WHEN A.CREDITS = B.CREDITS THEN    1 ELSE 0 END AS SAME
FROM @EmployeeProviders as A INNER JOIN @Providers as B ON A.ID = B.ID AND 
A.PLAN_ID = B.PLAN_ID AND A.effective_date = '2013-07-01'
)

SELECT *
FROM TEMP AS A INNER JOIN 
(SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID , PLAN_ID , SUM(SAME) AS TOTAL , COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM TEMP GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID ,   PLAN_ID ) AS B  
ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND A.PLAN_ID = B.PLAN_ID
WHERE B.TOTAL != B.CNT
```